# Try/Catch not working for WP8 C# .NET with Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I'm playing around with this block of code:

```
 try
 {
   mscvUser = imstUser
    .Where(User => User.Id == intId)
    .Take(1000)
    .ToCollectionView();
 }
 catch(MobileServiceInvalidOperationException f){

  MessageBox.Show(f.ToString());

 }
```

It works fine normally, but I've been deliberately disconnecting my Internet for testing purposes, and I keep hitting MobileServiceInvalidOperationException, but it won't catch it in that block; it throws it back to App.xaml.cs, breaks, and shuts down the app.

Comment: try to catch `Exception`, find out the real type, and make sure it is the above

Comment: Catching `Exception` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using the newest version of Azure Mobile Services. The SDK was recently updated to version 1.0:
http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/

I checked with this version and the exception is catched correctly.

In the newest version, "ToCollectionView" was replaced and you'd now have to use

```
try
 {
   mscvUser = await imstUser
    .Where(User => User.Id == intId)
    .Take(1000)
    .ToCollectionAsync();
 }
 catch(MobileServiceInvalidOperationException f){

  MessageBox.Show(f.ToString());

 }
```

Hope this helps

edit:
Here from the changelog:

> MobileServiceTable.ToCollectionView() is now ToCollection(): the collection view implementation had some bugs, and it has been rewritten.

[As you can read here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/03/14/azure-mobile-services-managed-client-upcoming-breaking-changes.aspx)

Comment: I'm using 1.0 and I don't have ToCollectionAsync(). Odd.

Comment: I just checked in a new project. Only ToCollectionAsync() is available as an extension methode, which means you need to have the using statement `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;` I would suggest you try to reinstall the sdk. I've had problems with nuget before.

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem, apparently I was using the old MobileServices somehow even though the new one was installed. I've got the new one only now, I need to go back and change a lot of things now to make it work. I'll report back after everything's done.

Comment: I've run into another problem, that MobileServiceTableSerializer no longer exists in 1.0.

Comment: It appears to all be working now, thanks. Other users should be wary of the change in 1.0.

Comment: @user2070752 Could you mark this (and possibly the rest of your questions) as answered? Would be appreciated :)